# LINUX field error expecting 8 fields but found 9

Tags: linux, python

I am new to both Linux and Python, and I am a facing a field problem in a file while running it in Linux. I am pasting a sample of the data from Notepad++ for reference. I have also attached a screenshot of the error. I thought it might have something to do with CRLF (hidden character), but I tried changing it to Unix via the EOL option in Notepad++, then Linux returns the error saying that now it has found 12 fields instead of 8. What python commands can I use to identify or to set the number of fields to 8 for rows 2, 4, 6 and so on ? or Can I do this in Notepad++?
Thank you, 
[image]

```
266566 3
1 0.524590 0.10 0.05 1.00 0.45 5.00 0.50 
  5.175 5.175 5.175 5.175 5.175 5.175 5.175 5.175 5.175 5.175 5.175 5.175 
6 0.311475 0.10 0.10 1.00 0.65 1.00 0.25 
  0.087 0.112 0.125 0.263 0.812 2.338 3.425 2.963 2.550 1.600 0.375 0.125 
7 0.163934 0.10 0.10 1.00 0.65 1.00 0.25 
  0.275 0.300 0.350 0.650 1.112 1.900 2.050 1.775 1.262 0.625 0.388 0.312
```

Comment: What is "it"? you will need to be more specific than "Linux and Python" - what specific python program are you trying to execute, and what is the origin of the data?

Comment: It's model built in C to run on Linux.

Comment: you asked `Can I do this in Notepad++?`, but you did not say what you are trying to do

Comment: Can I make the number of fields in rows 2, 4,6 and so on to 8 instead of 9 in Notepad++?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, is there a way to remove this whitespace in all the rows in Notepad++?

Comment: Rows 2,4,6 have 8 fields if saved with LF. Rows 3,5,7 have 12 fields. Maybe that's not what your program is expecting?

Answer (score 0):

You could edit the file with vi, ed, or sed with:
/ $//
to remove trailing white space.
You might also have to remove carriage return if this is a file from windows with:
//r// (slash backslash slash r slash slash)